# Why 10251 and 10252 port not used in k8s control plane?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm following [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#check-required-ports) and am about to ask our IT team to open the hardware firewall port for me:

**Control-plane node(s)**

| Protocol | Direction | Port Range | Purpose | Used By |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCP | Inbound | 6443* | Kubernetes API server | All |
| TCP | Inbound | 2379-2380 | etcd server client API | kube-apiserver, etcd |
| TCP | Inbound | 10250 | kubelet API | Self, Control plane |
| TCP | Inbound | 10251 | kube-scheduler | Self |
| TCP | Inbound | 10252 | kube-controller-manager | Self |

**Worker node(s)**

| Protocol | Direction | Port Range | Purpose | Used By |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCP | Inbound | 10250 | kubelet API | Self, Control plane |
| TCP | Inbound | 30000-32767 | NodePort Services† | All |

Before I ask IT to open the hardware port for me, I checked my local environment which doesn't have a hardware firewall, and I see this:

```
# netstat -oanltp | grep 10250
tcp6       0      0 :::10250       :::*              LISTEN      3914/kubelet         off (0.00/0/0)
# netstat -oanltp | grep 10251
# netstat -oanltp | grep 10252
```

You can see that nothing is listening on `10251` and `10252`. But my `kube-scheduler` and `kube-controller-manager` are running, and everything looks OK:

```
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-shlava     1/1     Running     0          47h     10.192.244.109   
kube-system   kube-scheduler-shlava              1/1     Running     0          47h     10.192.244.109
```

So I wonder: is it normal that nothing is listening on `10251` and `10252`?

Comment: Are you really asking *"So I wonder: is it normal that nothing is listening on `10251` and `10252`?"* or is the **real** question *"Do I really need to ask IT to open ports `10251` and `10252`?"* ? Those *could* have different answers. (I don't use kubernetes, so I don't know whether they do, but they could.)

Comment: I'm not sure the difference here? I just don't know if any potential issue here if I don't ask IT to open the `10251` and `10252` in hardware firewall. And, if not open these 2 ports are ok, then better to know why K8S document give that guide to users, for my knowledge...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is: *it depends*.

- You may have specified a different port for serving HTTP with `--port` flag
- You may have disabled serving HTTP altogether with `--port 0`
- You are using latest version of K8s

Last one is most probable as [Creating a cluster with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) states it is written for version *1.21*

Ports `10251` and `10252` have been replaced in veresion *1.17* (see more [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.17.md#cluster-lifecycle-1))

> Kubeadm: enable the usage of the secure kube-scheduler and kube-controller-manager ports for health checks. For kube-scheduler was 10251, becomes 10259. For kube-controller-manager was 10252, becomes 10257.

Moreover, this functionality is depracted in *1.19* (more [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.19.md#deprecation))

> Kube-apiserver: the componentstatus API is deprecated. This API provided status of etcd, kube-scheduler, and kube-controller-manager components, but only worked when those components were local to the API server, and when kube-scheduler and kube-controller-manager exposed unsecured health endpoints. Instead of this API, etcd health is included in the kube-apiserver health check and kube-scheduler/kube-controller-manager health checks can be made directly against those components' health endpoints.

It seems some parts of documentation are outdated.